# DbContext Code First: creating multiple related entities

Tags: entity-framework, dbcontext

I have (what i think to be) a pretty standard problem.

[image: simple inheritance]

in my Manager entity, i have my Person referenced from Manager

```
[ForeignKey("PersonID")]
public Person Person { get; set; }
```

I'd like to create a new manager in one shot

```
var mgr = new Manager { Person = new Person() };
```

this fails with foreign key error, because the person does not yet exist.

i've made this work by saving the Person, and supplying person ID manually to new Manager { PersonID = myNewPerson.ID };

UPDATE

not sure if this matters, but my backed db is Oracle

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework is doing exactly what it's supposed to do, enforce a foreign key constraint. Think about it, in SQL, you couldn't insert into the `Manager` table without supplying a proper `PersonID`. One alternative would be to make PersonID a nullable foreign key

```
public int? PersonID { get; set; }
```

Comment: by adding the new person to a new manager, EF has enough information to know where to point the FK (it's a dependency on a person i just created). this style of adding works on a previously saved parent entity, so why shouldn't it work on a new one?

Comment: Because you didn't add the `Person` to the db context. I sort of see your point, but this functionality doesn't exist currently. Why, you ask? Because it hasn't been added...But EF6 is open sourced so fork and commit!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you are facing is that the database does not have any knowledge of your person. First you need to tell your db, hey this person should be added and then relate it to the Manager like this:

```
var p = new Person();
db.Persons.Add(p);
var m = new Manager { Person = p };
db.Managers.Add(m);
db.SaveChanges();
```

if you notice, you are telling your database in what order to insert the records. First you tell it to add the Person and once the person is in the database you can relate it to something else being pushed to the db. `DbContext` is capable of tracking all this logic.

Doing this you don't need to worry about ID's and your implementations look more like pure OOP.

hope this helps.

Comment: thanks but i already stated that this approach works. My question is why it doesn't work in a single statement, considering that EF has all the relationships. it's just a matter of saving in right order.